как работать с EditText во фрагменте
Нужно поменять свойство text в EditText который находится во фрагменте.
fragment_EditText
    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1PredmetMon"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Название предмета"
         android:textSize="11sp"
         android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
         android:textColorHint="@color/gray" />

fragment.java
public class fEnterMonday extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_enter_monday, null);
        final EditText editText1PredmetMon = (EditText) 
        v.findViewById(R.id.editText1PredmetMon);
        editText1PredmetMon.setText("text");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_enter_monday, container, false);
    }
}

текст просто не меняется. недавно начал изучать java и as, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка и как исправить?

В оператора return метода onCreateView вы заново создаете макет.
Замените выражение return inflater inflate(...) на return v;

спасибо, работает
